# How to dynamically set selected drop down value in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to set the selected value of a drop down in Angular 5.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="col-sm-3">
   <mat-select placeholder="State" name="state [formControl]="stateFormControl" required>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" value="{{state.key}}">{{state.name}}
     </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
   <mat-error *ngIf="stateFormControl.hasError('required')">State is required
   </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

TypeScript:

```
stateFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required
]);

this.vendorForm.controls["state"].setValue(this.state);
```

Even when I set the default value in the FormControl declaration, nothing is being set by default for the drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
this.stateFormControl.setValue(this.state);
```

or

```
<mat-form-field class="col-sm-3">
   <mat-select placeholder="State" name="state" formControlName="state" required>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" value="{{state.key}}">{{state.name}}
     </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
   <mat-error *ngIf="stateFormControl.hasError('required')">State is required
   </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

If you decide to change your html then follow [this tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#introduction-to-formbuilder) of reactive form

So you will build your form with something like this

```
buildForm(){
    this.vendorForm = this.fb.group({
      state: ['', Validators.required ], // <--- You don't need to instantiate FormControls
    });
}
```

and you will have this somewhere else

```
<form [formGroup]="vendorForm">
```

Comment: I already have this:
buildForm() {
        this.vendorForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            state: this.stateFormControl,
        });
    }

The above suggestions did not work

Comment: This is the problem. You don't need to instantiate FormControls yourself, try to copy my code to your buildForm method and delete the stateFormControl.

Comment: Ronaldo, how do I use the above errors with the reactive forms? They no longer work after switching?

Comment: just change to state: ['', Validators.required ]

Comment: I am having a few problems:
Switched my form to this:
*ngIf="vendor" [formGroup]="vendorForm"
Console is saying formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in

Switched Errors to:
*ngIf="state.hasError('required')"
Console Error:
Expected validator to return Promise or Observable
and
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined

Comment: I suggest follow the tutorial and if you still have problems create another question.

Answer (score 1):

Bind to the value attribute in your `<option>` tag:

```
<mat-select placeholder="State" name="state [formControl]="stateFormControl" required>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.key">{{state.name}}
     </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: This results in the following console error:
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{state.key}}] inng:///AppModule/NewVendorComponent.html@42:77 ("ormControl" required>
 <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [ERROR ->][value]="{{state.key}}">{{state.name}}
</mat-option>"):
ng:///AppModule/NewVendorComponent.html@42:77
Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 2 in [{{state.key}}] in ng:///AppModule/NewVendorComponent.html@42:77 ("ormControl" required>

Comment: Yes sorry remove {{}}. All you need is `state.key`, updated the code.

Comment: This works to set the value, but you won't be able to read it later. For that you would need to use ngModel. However, I prefer to user Reactive Forms.